# PhoneGap - Android viewport ignored (I know, I know)

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap

I can see this question has been asked a zillion times, but zero solutions have actually worked (may be because they're all very old?).

PhoneGap ignores pretty much all viewport strings. I can set `initial-scale` to values above 1, but can't use 0.5 or anything like that. `width=device-width` doesn't work neither does `width=500`.

I can't really play around in the Android Java settings, as PhoneGap ignores these too (at least in their device preview).

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Have you tried to see if these are ignored if you use the local cordova build?

Comment: By "device preview" you mean the phonegap developer app?